# Possible to add 32-bit ints with wraparound in J?

Tags: math, int, j

Is it possible to do arithmetic operations on numbers in `J` and have them behave like they would in a C-like language? I.e. if I start with a couple of 32-bit (or 64-bit, I suppose) numbers, is there any way to add or subtract them and have them overflow/underflow/wrap-around the way they would in C/C++/Java?

Comment: For those of us less familiar with C or Java, what behavior do you specifically want? For example, are you looking for FFFFFFFF plus 00000001 to equal 00000000?

Comment: Also, why? Are there problems you think are easier to solve with that behavior?

Comment: Your example captures the essence. My application for this is that I'm trying to implement [a toy virtual machine](http://boundvariable.org/task.shtml) in `J`, just for sport. Given that J can host its own UI, I figure it's up to this, but it's not looking like it wants to. :)

Comment: I want 32-bit `mul` behavior also. I guess I can just do mod 2^32 after each operation. That'll get me in the right neighborhood, but leaving some performance on the table.

Comment: Signed integers in C don't wrap around; that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @fuz I wasn't clear in my original post, but we're talking unsigned here.

Answer (score 1):

So, one direct way to handle overflows is with Residue (`|`):

```
   (2x ^ 32) | 4000000000 + 1000000000
705032704
   overflow =: ] |~ 2x ^ [
   32 overflow 4000000000 + 1000000000
705032704
```

You can produce a binary representation of your values with Base (`#.`) and Antibase (`#:`):

```
   [ reg =: (32 $ 2) #: 1 2 3 4294967294 4294967295 4294967296 4294967297
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   3 { reg
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
   #. 3 { reg
4294967294
   #. reg
1 2 3 4294967294 4294967295 0 1
   (32 $ 2)&#: #. +/ 0 2 { reg
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
   (32 $ 2)&#: #. +/ 0 4 { reg
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

There are probably some cooler ways to do this with the Foreign (`!:`) system functions, but those are beyond me.

Comment: I imagine you can get your binary multiplication by finding the indices (`I. |. 2 { reg`) and then shifting the value for each index (`1 |. 2 { reg`) and summing the results.